# screen coordinates to real world coordinates in opengl

Tags: opengl, opencv, coordinate-systems

This is actually mixing artoolkit and opencv.
Opencv gives screen coordinates of my fingers top.
Artoolkit gives modelview of marker,which in turn gives modelview of the object drawn over the AR marker
For the finger i have screen coordinates.
I need to compare them to check where did finger hits hit.
So how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

this post explains very nicely how to convert from image to world coordinates.

[Opencv virtually camera rotating/translating for bird's eye view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606891/opencv-virtually-camera-rotating-translating-for-birds-eye-view)

It is an extremely well-explained code. Now, if you need some of the parameters that go in those equations, this is another problem, and it can be only solved for specific situations. (Camera field of view,  rotation angles and translations)