# OpenCV findHomography Issue

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a Panography / Panorama application in OpenCV and I've run into a problem I really can't figure out. For an idea of what a panorama photograph looks like, have a look here at the Panography Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panography

So far, I can take multiple images, and stitch them together while making any image I like a reference image; here's a little taster of what I mean.

[image: An example Panography image I've created]

However, as you can see - it has a lot of issues. The primary one I am facing is that the images are getting cut (re: far right image, top of images). To highlight why this is happening, I'll draw the points that have been matched, and draw lines for where the transformation will end up:

[image: The image matches]

Where the left image is the reference image, and the right image is the image after it's been translated (original below) - I have drawn the green lines to highlight the image. The image has the following corner points:

```
TL: [234.759, -117.696]
TR: [852.226, -38.9487]
BR: [764.368, 374.84]
BL: [176.381, 259.953]
```

So the main problem I have is that after the perspective has been changed the image:

[image: Original Image]

Suffers losses like so:

[image: Cut up image]

Now enough images, some code.

I'm using a `cv::SurfFeatureDetector`, `cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor` and `cv::FlannBasedMatcher` to get all of those points, and I calculate the matches and more importantly good matches by doing the following:

```
/* calculate the matches */
for(int i = 0; i < descriptors_thisImage.rows; i++) {
    double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if(dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
    if(dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
}

/* calculate the good matches */
for(int i = 0; i < descriptors_thisImage.rows; i++) {
    if(matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist) {
        good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
    }
}
```

This is pretty standard, and to do this I followed the tutorial found here: http://opencv.itseez.com/trunk/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html

To copy images atop of one another, I use the following method (where `img1` and `img2` are `std::vector< cv::Point2f >`)

```
/* set the keypoints from the good matches */
for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ ) {
    img1.push_back( keypoints_thisImage[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
    img2.push_back( keypoints_referenceImage[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
}

/* calculate the homography */
cv::Mat H = cv::findHomography(cv::Mat(img1), cv::Mat(img2), CV_RANSAC);

/* warp the image */
cv::warpPerspective(thisImage, thisTransformed, H, cv::Size(thisImage.cols * 2, thisImage.rows * 2), cv::INTER_CUBIC );

/* place the contents of thisImage in gsThisImage */
thisImage.copyTo(gsThisImage);

/* set the values of gsThisImage to 255 */
for(int i = 0; i < gsThisImage.rows; i++) {
    cv::Vec3b *p = gsThisImage.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < gsThisImage.cols; j++) {
        for( int grb=0; grb < 3; grb++ ) {
            p[j][grb] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>( 255.0f );
        }
    }
}

/* convert the colour to greyscale */
cv::cvtColor(gsThisImage, gsThisImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);

/* warp the greyscale image to create an image mask */
cv::warpPerspective(gsThisImage, thisMask, H, cv::Size(thisImage.cols * 2, thisImage.rows * 2), cv::INTER_CUBIC );

/* stitch the transformed image to the reference image */
thisTransformed.copyTo(referenceImage, thisMask);
```

So, I have the coordinates of where the warped image is going to end up, I have the points that create the homogeneous matrix that's used for these transformations - but I can't figure out how I should go about translating these images so they can't get cut up. Any help or pointers are very appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, why didn't you use the newly added stitching module? It does exactly the thing you're trying to do.

Second, if you want to continue with your code, to correct it it's easy. In the homography matrix, the translations represent the values on the last column.

```
a11 a12 a13 t1
a21 a22 a23 t2
a31 a32 a33 t3
a41 a42 a43 1
```

(If you have a 3x3 matrix, you will miss the a13..a43 column and the a41..1 row. a33 will (should) become 1).

So, what you have to do is to figure out what you should put in the last column so that yout images are aligned.

Check also this post that explaines (somehow the opposite problem) how to build a homography, when you know the camera parameters. It will help you understand the role of the matrix values.

[Opencv virtually camera rotating/translating for bird's eye view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606891/opencv-virtually-camera-rotating-translating-for-birds-eye-view)

And **note** that everything I told you about last column is only approximate, because the values in the last column are actually translation plus some (minor) factors.

Comment: Ahh, I see - so before I run cv::warpPerspective I edit the values in the holography? It's so obvious now! So many thanks! Also, I'll look into the image stitching module and add it as an option (also using the GPU and CPU to compare the differences) - just trying to learn OpenCV. :-)

Comment: Glad to see your nice results!

Answer (score 1):

Once you find you matrices you should just compute the transformations for the corners and collect minmum and maximum x and y values for the transformed points.

Once you have this bounding box just translate all matrices by `(-xmin,-ymin)` and allocate for result an image that is `(xmax-xmin)` wide and `(ymax-ymin)` tall and then draw all transformed images into that.

With this approach you will have black regions around the stitching but no clipping.

Automatically finding instead the largest rectangle contained in the stitching (to get a full merged image with no black areas and minimal clipping) is quite a bit more annoying to implement.