# What is the simplest way to detect the angle of rotation between two images of the same dimensions (184, 184)?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

Some posts recommend [homography decomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271150/how-to-calculate-rotation-and-translation-matrices-from-homography), but is there a simpler way (e.g., converting the images to NumPy arrays and using Pillow methods)?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Any method that would solve this for equilateral triangles would come up with 3 unique solutions. Thus there is no one solution.

Comment: Please provide representative images - the examples you show have simple and obvious solutions - which won't work for real-world images.

Comment: Do you know which corners correspond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made up this very basic algorithm to calculate the angle of rotation. It rotates the second image with 1 degree and calculate the mean square error (MSE) for each angle between 0 and 360 degrees. The rotation angle that we are looking for should be corresponding to the minimal MSE.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
import numpy as np
import math 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rmsdiff(x, y):
  """Calculates the root mean square error (RSME) between two images"""
  errors = np.asarray(ImageChops.difference(x, y)) / 255
  return math.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(errors)))


im1 = Image.open("1.png")

im2 = Image.open("2.png")
print(im1)

mse = []
for i in range(360):
  im2_rot = im2.rotate(i)
  mse.append(rmsdiff(im1,im2_rot))

print(mse.index(min(mse))) # outputs 90 degrees
plt.plot(mse)
plt.show()
```

In the case of the images in the question this is the MSE plot, and the minimum MSE is corresponding to 90 degrees.

[image]