# Can I convert screen coord to camera coordinate using this procedure?

Tags: opencv, camera, screen, coordinate

I want to find camera coordinate from pixel/screen coordinate using opencv.

Suppose my cameras are calibrated and I got intrinsic parameter (matrix with focal length and principal point)
and extrinsic parameter (rotation and translation matrix) using opencv. Then [this website](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) for 3d 
reconstruction with opencv says:

```
s * [q  1]^{Transpose} = [K] * [([R] * P) + T]
```

where `[q]` is 2d pixel coordinate, `s = 1`, `K` is a (`3x3`) intrinsic matrix, `R` is a (`3x3`)  rotation matrix, `P` is
(`3x1`) in world coordinate and `T` is a (`3x1`) translation matrix.

So:

```
[R]^{-1} * ( [ [K]^{-1} * [q  1 ]^{Transpose} ] - [T] ) = [P]
```

And then:

```
[U] = ([R] * [P]) + [T]
```

where `[U]` is (`3x1`) in camera coordinate. So now `[q]` which is in pixel coordinate will be
converted to camera coordinate `[U]`.

Am I right to convert pixel coordinate to camera coordinate like this? Is rotation matrix (`[R]`) or intrinsic matrix (`[K]`) always invertible? Or are
there times when rotation matrix and/or intrinsic matrix can't be inverted?

Is it possible to kindly confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am too lazy to check that for you (actually, you should test it, and if you have questions, come here for help).

But you can use this nice code snippet: it's not exactly what you want, but the fundamentals are right:

[Opencv virtually camera rotating/translating for bird's eye view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606891/opencv-virtually-camera-rotating-translating-for-birds-eye-view)

Comment: Thanks vasile for your help. I'll try it myself. Thanks again.