# Compensate rotation from successive images

Tags: c++, opencv, rotation, translation

Lets say I have `image1` and `image2` obtained from a webcam. For taking the `image2`, the webcam undergoes a rotation (yaw, pitch, roll) and a translation.

**What I want:** Remove the rotation from `image2` so that only the translation remains (to be precise: my tracked points `(x,y)` from `image2` will be rotated to the the same values as in `image1` so that only the translation component remains).

**What I have done/tried so far:**

- I tracked corresponding features from `image1` and `image2`.
- Calculated the fundamental matrix `F` with `RANSAC` to remove outliers.
- Calibrated the camera so that I got a `CAM_MATRIX` (fx, fy and so on).
- Calculated Essential Matrix from `F` with `CAM_Matrix` (`E = cam_matrix^t * F * cam_matrix`)
- Decomposed the E matrix with OpenCV's SVD function so that I have a rotation matrix and translation vector.
  -I know that there are 4 combinations and only 1 is the right translation vector/rotation matrix.

**So my thought was:** I know that the camera movement from `image1` to `image2` won't be more than lets say about 20°/AXIS so I can eliminate at least 2 possibilities where the angles are too far off.

For the 2 remaining I have to triangulate the points and see which one is the correct one (I have read that I only need 1 , but due possible errors/outliers it should be done with some more to be sure which one is the right). I think I could use the OpenCV's triangulation function for this? Is my thought right so far? Do I need to calculate the projection error?

**Let's move on and assume that I finally obtained the right `R|t` matrix**. 
How do I continue? I tried to multiply the normal, as well as transposed rotation matrix which should reverse the rotation (?) (for testing purpose I just tried both possible combinations of R|t, I have not done the triangulation in code yet) with a tracked point in `image2`. but the calculated point is way too far off from what it should be. Do I need the calibration matrix here as well?

**So how can I invert the rotation applied to `image2`?** (to be exact, apply the inverse rotation to my `std::vector<cv::Point2f>` array which contains the tracked (x,y) points from `image2`)

**Displaying the de-rotated image would be also nice to have.** This is done with `warpPerspective` function? Like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606891/opencv-virtually-camera-rotating-translating-for-birds-eye-view) ?

(I just don't fully understand what the purpose of A1/A2 and dist in the T matrix is or how I can adopt this solution to solve my problem.)