# "Bird's eye view" transformation on a given Image with known intrinsic parameters

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration, homography

I am trying to get a bird's eye view transformation on a given Image.
Using `cv2.calibrateCamera` and `cv2.solvePnPRansac`, I know the intrinsic parameters of the camera.

I have found many posts suggesting many different answers, but none worked for me. Some examples of posts which I have tried:

1. [Python create image with new camera position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45811421/python-create-image-with-new-camera-position)
2. [Bird's eye view perspective transformation from camera calibration opencv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576087/birds-eye-view-perspective-transformation-from-camera-calibration-opencv-python)
3. [OpenCV: get perspective matrix from translation & rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275877/opencv-get-perspective-matrix-from-translation-rotation)

None of them worked, some resulted in black images while others in strange warps which make no sense. I know the intrinsic parameters I computed are correct because I can re-project my model back on the original image points.

Camera matrix for this image:

[image: camera matrix]

Rotation vector:

[image: rotation vector]

Translation vector:

[image]

The latest code I have used it this:

```py
def get_birds_eye_view(image, camera_matrix, rotation_vec, translation_vec):

    dst = np.zeros_like(image)

    dx, dy, dz = translation_vec

    A1= np.matrix([[1, 0, -image.shape[1]/2],
                    [0, 1, -image.shape[0]/2],
                    [0, 0, 0   ],
                    [0, 0, 1   ]])

    T = np.matrix([[1,0,0,dx],
                    [0,1,0,dy],
                    [0,0,1,dz],
                    [0,0,0,1]])

    rotation_matrix = cv2.Rodrigues(rotation_vec)[0]

    rotation_matrix = np.c_[ rotation_matrix, np.zeros(3)]
    rotation_matrix = np.r_[ rotation_matrix, [[0, 0, 0, 1]] ]
    camera_matrix = np.c_[ camera_matrix, np.zeros(3)]

    invers_camera_matrix = np.zeros((4,3))
    invers_camera_matrix[:3,:3] = np.linalg.inv(camera_matrix[:3,:3])
    invers_camera_matrix[-1,:] = [0, 0, 1]

    H = np.linalg.multi_dot([camera_matrix, rotation_matrix, T, invers_camera_matrix])

    warped_image = cv2.warpPerspective(image, H, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]), dst, cv2.INTER_NEAREST, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 0)

    return warped_image
```

Example image:

[image]

Output is just black:
[image]

The desired output might look like this (but with a bad not a chess board, image taken from second link):

[image]

If any information is missing please comment and I'll provide the data.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: how do I get the bird's eye view transformation using  intrinsic parameters of the camera.

Comment: Can you please show the actual code you've tried to use?

Comment: Sure, I tried ,any different things. ill post the latest one. None of them actually worked.

Comment: What is the specific problem with that particular code you've shown?

Comment: It returns really strange results. I'll post the one corresponding to the image I uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

look at this page, and you will find answer.
Maybe your T is not good.
https://gist.github.com/anujonthemove/7b35b7c1e05f01dd11d74d94784c1e58

actually I could not understand why this T is setted by 500.

Comment: did you  aldready solved this problem? if yes , please share with me. thanks

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”